# What is the thread size/measurement of the derailleur barrel adjuster?

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear, barrel-adjuster

The barrel adjuster threads on my commuter bike's RD have been marred when the barrel adjuster got bludgeoned on a side crash and I want to chase the threads before screwing in the replacement barrel adjuster.

My derailleur is a Shimano Deore. (in case different brands have different stuff)

Comment: Dunno about Shimano derailers, but was working on a bike Tuesday where the adjuster on a brake lever was mucked, and went through five different sizes before I found the right one.

Comment: I'll try and find a deore derialleur and check the threads for you tomorrow.. If it's metric I'll give you the size. Might differ between different models/years of deore though